# Common results of two MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I am looking to combine two MySQL queries so it returns the common results so I know I am not looking to use UNION on this one. I tried writing a subselect statement but that didn't work out

First query:

```
SELECT s.ses_id, h.page, m.question, m.answer FROM session s
INNER JOIN history h on h.ses_id = s.ses_id
INNER JOIN multiple m on m.ses_id = s.ses_id    
WHERE m.question = 4 and m.answer = 3 and h.page = 4
```

Second query:

```
SELECT s.ses_id, h.page, m.question, m.answer FROM session s
INNER JOIN history h on h.ses_id = s.ses_id
INNER JOIN multiple m on m.ses_id = s.ses_id    
WHERE m.question = 114 and m.answer = 1 and h.page = 114
```

Failed merge query:

```
SELECT s.ses_id FROM session s, multiple, history h
JOIN (
    SELECT session.ses_id
    FROM session, history, multiple
    WHERE multiple.question = 114 and multiple.answer = 1 and history.page = 114 and history.ses_id = session.ses_id and multiple.ses_id=session.ses_id
    ) q1 ON q1.ses_id = s.ses_id
WHERE s.interview = 'lifestyle' and s.finished = 'y' and multiple.page=4 and multiple.answer = 3 and h.page = 4 and h.ses_id = s.ses_id and multiple.ses_id=s.ses_id
```

The multiple table contains questions and answers and I am looking to find the ids of those who have answered the two questions with those specific answers.

I realize this should be easy and I am most likely overthinking and/or missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to join both the `history` and `multiple` tables an additional time each for the 2nd question/answer combination.

```
SELECT s.ses_id,
       m1.question, m1.answer, h1.page,
       m2.question, m2.answer, h2.page
FROM session s
INNER JOIN history h1
   ON h1.ses_id = s.ses_id AND h1.page = 4
INNER JOIN multiple m1
   ON m1.ses_id = s.ses_id
   AND m1.question = 4 AND m1.answer = 3
INNER JOIN history h2
   ON h2.ses_id = s.ses_id AND h2.page = 114
INNER JOIN multiple m2
   ON m2.ses_id = s.ses_id
   AND m2.question = 114 and m2.answer = 1
WHERE s.interview = 'lifestyle' and s.finished = 'y'
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked out for what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Below simply altered query may be useful.,

```
SELECT s.ses_id, h.page, m.question, m.answer FROM session s
INNER JOIN history h on h.ses_id = s.ses_id
INNER JOIN multiple m on m.ses_id = s.ses_id    
WHERE 
( m.question = 4 and m.answer = 3 and h.page = 4 )
OR
( m.question = 114 and m.answer = 1 and h.page = 114 )
```

Merge operation is not needed.

Comment: I don't think so. The OP is looking for records of users that have answered *both* questions, not one or the other.

Comment: This will return the conjuction of the two sets, not their intersection

Comment: Yes, I agree it fails in one case

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for intersection of two queries then you can simply use `IN` set operator of mysql

```
SELECT s.ses_id, h.page, m.question, m.answer
FROM session s
   INNER JOIN history h on h.ses_id = s.ses_id
   INNER JOIN multiple m on m.ses_id = s.ses_id    
WHERE m.question = 4 and m.answer = 3 and h.page = 4 and s.ses_id 
IN
(
   SELECT s.ses_id
   FROM session s
      INNER JOIN history h on h.ses_id = s.ses_id
      INNER JOIN multiple m on m.ses_id = s.ses_id    
   WHERE m.question = 114 and m.answer = 1 and h.page = 114
)
```